# How to make the text responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

can someone help me to make this responsive. Im trying to make it fit an tablet and phone screen. But i cant make it work.

```css
.slide-right {
  left: 38%;
  right:50%;
  top: 20%;
  position: absolute;
}
.image-desc {
  width: 750px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 23%;
  right:50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
}
.image-desc h3 {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color:  #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-right wow pulse" >
</div>
<div class="image-desc wow fadeInUp">
  <h3> KÖP AV OSS </h3>
 <h3> tel: 07071965063 </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `.image-desc` has fixed size, make it in `%`, also I think you can make `.image-desc h3` font-size adjustments with media queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a code example of what you can do.
Add this code to your `.css` file :

**Desktop font size**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .image-desc h3{ font-size: 30px; }
}
```

**Tablets & phablets font size**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
   .image-desc h3{ font-size: 20px; }
}
```

**Phones font size**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .image-desc h3{ font-size: 15px; }
}
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: This will not work if the text string something like "dssaddadadadadadadadadadadadsadadadsadadsadad" after this it will not responsive any more.

Comment: @BhavinSolanki you can use `word-break: break-all` for the issue you reported.

Comment: @BhavinSolanki works with this type of string. You talk about ellipsis?

Comment: @Mordecai yes, this is the solution not only decreasing the font size.

Comment: @Gregdebrick please check `Mordecai` comment